# mock fs.readFile - Unit test

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, fs

I am using Jest framework for unit testing and came across a scenario to mock the fs.readFile.I have used spyOn and mocked the implementation.My code below

**test_file.ts**

```
import * as fs from 'fs';


it('read File',  () => {

    const spy = jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFile')
                    .mockImplementation((_, callback) => callback(null, Buffer.from('Sample')));

    // Calling the function
    myFunction('./path');

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

The spy is not called when i run the test case and the mock is not working.The original implementation is always working.

**My function using fs.readFile**

```
myFunction = (path) => {
    // Reading the file
    fs.readFile(path, async (error, file) => {
        console.log(error)      // No such file error thrown instead  of null
        /**  Block of code with async work**/   
    });
};
```

**Briefly,what i am trying to do**

How to mock the fs.readFile correctly ?

**EDIT**
When i tried to console the error in my original callback function,it threw error 'no such file' . But i am expecting the error to be null since I am mocking it to return value as null.

Comment: I just tested with ```function myFunction(path) { fs.readFile(path, (error, res) => console.log('error', error, 'res', res)); }``` and it works properly. Are you sure there's no issue with your function? **EDIT:** Be aware that the callback shouldn't be ```async```.

Comment: I just tested with your version and it seems to be working fine. What's the current output?

Comment: Yes,my callback is async as it does some db work inside .What should i do now ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: You mentioned **Be aware that the callback shouldn't be async**.But my fs.readFile callback is async

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue. Can you please elaborate? What output are you getting? Any errors? Are tests failing?

Comment: When i tried to console the error in my original callback function,it threw error 'no such file' . But i am expecting the error to be null since I am mocking it to return value as null.

Comment: The test is passing when using your code. Are you sure you are importing the same ```fs``` module on both places? Can you post a full example (all files including imports)?

Comment: yes, that was the problem here ! import statements were different..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @JC Olivares,

'fs' import was the problem here.In the test case file, i imported 'fs' as

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

But the file with function had import

```
import fs from 'fs';
```